# how can I name my csv file as timestamp when getting data from twint

Tags: python, string, timestamp, filenames, twint

I am using twint for web crawling data form twitter. For that reason whenever I save my output file as csv, I want to name current timestamp but it is giving me an error

```
inport twint
c = twint.Config()
c.Search = "NationBehindState"
c.Limit = 10
c.Store_csv = True
c.Output =str(dt_string)+"g.csv"
```

[image]

However if I simply name any file with string in c.Output, file is created without any issue

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
from datetime import datetime
dt = datetime.now()
date = dt.strftime('%Y_%m_%d_%H_%M_%S')
file = open(f'{date}.csv', 'w+')
file.write(data)
file.close()
```

This will give you accuracy down the second and includes the year so will never risk repeating. If you need other formatting, look here:
https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html#strftime-and-strptime-format-codes